# Simple lookup using two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with pandas and my intention is to bring data from one table to other. Suppose I have two dataframes named df1 and df2:

df1 is like that:

```
Name    Age    Height
Marcus  18     170
Dan     21     172
Phill   30     165
Paty    24     160
Linda   25     158
```

df2 is like that:

```
Name    Score1    Score2     Score3
Dan          A         C          C
Paty         B         A          B
Marcus       C         D          B
Zoe          A         A          B
```

I would like to find a way to pick the ages of the guys in df1 and bring it to df2, resulting in a table like that:

```
Name    Score1    Score2     Score3    Age
Dan          A         C          C    21
Paty         B         A          B    24
Marcus       C         D          B    18
Zoe          A         A          B    NaN
```

In Excel we use VLOOKUP function in df2 to df1. But I could not find something similar in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use map or merge, map would be faster

Option 1: Using map

```
df2['Age'] = df2['Name'].map(df1.set_index('Name')['Age'])
```

Option 2: Using merge

```
df2.merge(df1[['Name', 'Age']], 'left')
```

Either way you get

```
    Name    Score1  Score2  Score3  Age
0   Dan     A       C       C       21.0
1   Paty    B       A       B       24.0
2   Marcus  C       D       B       18.0
3   Zoe     A       A       B       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help, @Vaishali. It worked well with "merge", but not with "map". I tried many times, but the message showed is the same: "_A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead_
". Perhaps "map" be a function more appropriated to be used with Series, not with Data Frames.

Comment: You can use merge but map is more efficient, especially for large datasets. The error message means that one of your dataframes was created as a copy. How did you create df1 and df2?

Comment: Yes,  @Vaishali. You are right: df2 was created as a copy. Thank you again!